# Include scripts before <body> php

Tags: php

Is there a way to inject scripts into the page before the `<body>` tag in php? I've seen some examples on how to do this with jquery, but jquery causes parts of my site not to function properly therefore I need a php code so I can selectively inject scripts before the opening  tag of my page.

ie.

```
.....
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.internads.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){       

        // Call Intern Ads              
        $().tcInternAds({
            title: "Support Our Sponsors!",
            url: "adpage.html",
            timeout: 10,
            deplay: 0,
            wait: 0,
            closeable: true
        });

    });

</script>
<body>
<div class="xxxxx">
...............</div>
```

I would like to be able to use php if possible, so I can include the code in my template files where I need the scripts to be called while avoiding global inclusion.

Can anyone help with this?

best,
Mike

Comment: Are you using a template manager? Something like http://www.smarty.net/ or you're just including a template.php file that contains the html template of your site?

Comment: Im using Social engine which is an extension of zend framework. The site uses .tpl files where headers are included from a global file.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't simply placing it within the `<head>` work?

```
<head>
.....
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.internads.js"></script>
<script>

    $(window).load()(function(){       

        // Call Intern Ads              
        $().tcInternAds({
            title: "Support Our Sponsors!",
            url: "adpage.html",
            timeout: 10,
            deplay: 0,
            wait: 0,
            closeable: true
        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="xxxxx">
...............</div>
```

Comment: No, Unfortunately I have a music player stops working when I include this globally.

Comment: So what **do** you want to do, place it before `<body>` but not within `<head>`? No, thats not possible...

Comment: Within head would be fine, as long as the scripts are loaded before the body then it will work for my needs.

Comment: Then you could replace the `$.ready()` function with `$(window).load()`, whichs runs when all assets are loaded, as opposed to waiting until the whole DOM is rendered.

Comment: Ahh... That makes sense. Let me give that a try Jeroen, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have had no luck with this solution. It looks like I may be able to do this using `preg_replace` to replace my body tag `<body id="global_page_music-index-browse">` with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.internads.js"></script>
<script>
    $(window).load()(function(){       
....
</script><body id="global_page_music-index-browse">`. My problem is i have no idea how to implement this.

Comment: That's really not how you should write a web application... Also, why didn't it work?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11788/discussion-between-mike-m-and-jeroen)

Answer (score 0):

Put your contents in index.php (or whatever it's called).

It should look like this:

```
<?php

...phpcode...

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.internads.js"></script>
<script>
...
</script>
<body>
<div class="xxxxx">

<?php

another php code

?>

</div>
```

Comment: I have pages that are generated dynamically using php and template files. Just adding the code to my template files means there will be 2 body tags... this is my dilemma. Thank you for your answer Radio.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem without having to inject or replace head code. The problem is that my site includes mootools and jquery is conflicting with it. I resolved the issue by using jQuery noConflict which defines a namespace to use and thus resolves the issue by using a custom variable rather than the dollar $.

Here is my working solution to workaround jquery/mootools conflict.

```
<link href="/internAds.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.internads.js"></script>
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(){      

        // Call Intern Ads              
        $j().tcInternAds({
            title: "Support Our Sponsors!",
            url: "/adpage.html",
            timeout: 15,
            deplay: 0,
            wait: 5,
            closeable: false
        });

    });

</script>
```

I appreciate everyone's time, I am not sure how I overlooked the conflict.

best,